# R: odbcDriverConnect Server name includes escape character

Tags: sql-server, r, odbc

I am successfully querying what I need from the first Server with the following:

```
library(RODBC)
library(data.table)
library(sqldf)
library(zoo)
library(forecast)
library(plyr)
library(parallel)

myconn <- odbcDriverConnect("SERVER=SQL12p4;DRIVER=SQL Server")

ManagementHours <- sqlQuery(myconn, " SELECT .......")
```

However when I try to connect to a different server `SQL12P4\VSQL1` I am unable to connect. I know that the `\` is an escape character and I believe that is my problem. I am wondering if there is a way to get around this? Below is the R command I am currently using.

```
myconn1 <- odbcDriverConnect("SERVER=SQL12P4\VSQL1;DRIVER= SQL SERVER")


> myconn1A <-odbcDriverConnect("SERVER=SQL12P4\VSQL1;DRIVER= SQL SERVER")
Error: '\V' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""SERVER=SQL12P4\V"
> myconn1B <-odbcDriverConnect("SERVER=SQL12P4\\VSQL1;DRIVER= SQL SERVER")
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("SERVER=SQL12P4\\VSQL1;DRIVER= SQL SERVER") :
 [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect("SERVER=SQL12P4\\VSQL1;DRIVER= SQL SERVER") :
  ODBC connection failed
```

Comment: You need to include the error messages. *"I am unable to connect"* is not helpful at all.

Comment: How about `odbcDriverConnect("SERVER=SQL12P4\\VSQL1;DRIVER= SQL SERVER")`? (Two back-slashes.) If not, four? (Eight would be *crazy* ...)

Comment: @nrussell thanks your answer was also not helpful at all

Comment: It wasn't meant to be an answer, but it was helpful since it got you to include necessary information in your question, which *you should have done in the first place.*

Comment: For ODBC drivers, you may been braces as well as credentials: *odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=servername;database=databasename;trusted_connection=yes;UID=username;PWD=password')*